# How to get the max value from a dictionary inside of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
a_dictionary = {"a": {"green_count: 12"}, "b": {"green_count: 13"}, "c": {"green_count: 2"}}
```

How can I find the highest `green_count` value and return the key 'b'?

I know how to do this for a value directly inside a dictionary key `max_key = max(a_dictionary, key=a_dictionary.get` however I don't know how to do this for a value that is inside a dictionary in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really have a nested dictionary (and thus that you syntax is incorrect):

```
a_dictionary = {"a": {"green_count": 12}, "b": {"green_count": 13}, "c": {"green_count": 2}}

max(a_dictionary, key=lambda x: a_dictionary[x].get('green_count',0))
```

Output: `'b'`

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a `NestedDict`. Install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) first

```
pip install ndicts
```

Then

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

a_dictionary = {"a": {"green_count": 12}, "b": {"green_count": 13}, "c": {"green_count": 2}}
nd = NestedDict(a_dictionary)

maximum = max(nd.values())
```

This works with nested dictionaries of any depth.